# If a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is linearly independant, then does that mean the set spans $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for example, and they are linearly independant that means the set does not lie in a plane nor a line, so it must span $\mathbb{R}^3$. Alternatively if the same set is linearly dependant then at most, the set will span $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is my intuition correct?

I know how to show a weather a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independant or dependant but I'm not sure how to show that they indeed span $\mathbb{R}^n$. Could I get some help understanding?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you need $n$ linearly independent vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^3$, but both vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: The set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is linearly independent, but only spans a plane, not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Do you notice anything from this example?

Comment: @William funny we came up with the exact same example seconds apart :)

Comment: @Ty Jensen we really are lazy, aren't we :)

Comment: @TyJensen how can i show this?

Comment: @TyJensen Im not sure how to show it generally

Comment: @notgauss The first comment here proves $n$ linearly independent vectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986257/does-every-linearly-independent-set-of-n-vectors-in-rn-forms-a-basis-in-rn

Comment: @TyJensen wow i think that is beyond my scope. Im barely 4 weeks into a linear algebra course. Is there no other way to show this?

Comment: @William Here is one way, although I do not really see why you would need to prove this for an LA class, it pretty much is the definition of span. A neat result is that (for finite dimensional vector spaces) if $W$ is a subspace of $V$, and $\dim W =\dim V$, then $W=V$. So if $\text{Span}(v_1,\dots v_n)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, you have that $\dim\text{Span}(v_1,\dots v_n)=n$, therefore $\text{Span}(v_1,\dots v_n) = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: "I'm barely 4 weeks into a linear algebra course." Then all I can say is, have patience! You will learn some shortcuts shortly. Until then, you should probably practice applying the definition of spanning because, even though it's not quite as simple as linear independence, it's important that you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

No, a set of linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ need not generate all of $\mathbb{R}^n$: consider, as mentioned in the comments, $\operatorname{span}(\{e_1, e_2 \})$: it's clearly $2$-dimensional and doesn't generate all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. On the other hand, a set of $n$ linearly independent vectors $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must necessarily span all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Otherwise, there would exist $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n, v\}$ is a set of $n + 1$ linearly independent vectors, which [cannot happen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249040/why-do-n-linearly-independent-vectors-span-mathbbrn). And no, if a set  $\{v_1, \cdots, v_m \}$ is linearly dependent, then it *can* generate any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you desire: this can easily be seen by taking the vectors $e_1, \cdots, e_n, 2e_1$, for example - it's a linearly dependent set but it generates all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What you need to look at in that case is $\dim(\operatorname{span}(\{v_1, \cdots, v_m \}))$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example I can think of is singleton sets.

Consider a vector $e \ne 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then it is easy to see that $\{e\}$ is linearly independent (by definition) but obviously it does not span $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n >1$